# How do I go to the Shell page and leave the menu button?

Tags: c#, shell, xamarin

If I navigate to other pages from the Shell menu items then I have the option to open the pull-out menu again.
And if I go to the page from the code inside, then the menu button at the top left is no longer there.

```
 await Shell.Current.GoToAsync("step");
```

How to open a page from the code and what would be in the open page was the shell menu button?

Comment: What is the step in you project? Does this page in the Shell structure? Could you provide more details for this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you navigate to the page that exists as part of the Shell visual hierarchy and register the route like below.

```
  <ShellContent
        Title="Page1"
        ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate local:Page1}"
        Icon="tab_about.png"
        Route="about" />
```

It could navigate with the parameter like below.

```
 await Shell.Current.GoToAsync("//about");
```

When you navigate, the hamburger icon would still be there.

If you navigate to the page that not exist in Shell visual hierarchy and register using `Routing.RegisterRoute`, it would cover all the page and the hamburger icon would not show. But you could back to the Shell with the back button on top left.

```
  Routing.RegisterRoute("step", typeof(Page2));
```

Answer (score 0):

The edit queue is always full! So here is my expansion of Wendy's answer:

**TLDR**:

Essentially the Hamburger Nav is only visible on Pages that are added or registered to the Shell or one of its child `BaseShellItem`s and thus are apart of the Shell Visual Hierarchy ->
If the Page is registered via AppShell.xaml ([can also be added programmatically](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66036972/11596811)) then the Page is being added to a `BaseShellItem` and is apart of the Shell Visual Hierarchy.

---

There are several ways to register a page for navigation and that determines whether the page is displayed with a hamburger:

1. If register a page via the AppShell.xaml like:

```xml
      <ShellContent
            Title="This is Page1"
            ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate local:Page1}"
            Icon="tab_about.png"
            Route="Page1" />
```

you can navigate with the parameter like below.

```
 await Shell.Current.GoToAsync("//Page1");
```

When you navigate, the hamburger icon would still be there, as the page is added to a `BaseShellItem`( `BaseShellItem`->`ShellContent`).

2. If you register a page not in the `AppShell.xaml` but via `Routing`:

```cs
Routing.RegisterRoute(nameof(page1), typeof(Page1));
```

and navigate to the page, it would cover all the page and the hamburger icon would not show, as its not added to a `BaseShellItem`. But you could go back to the Shell with the back button on top left.

3. You can register the Page (as of Xamarin.Forms 5) by adding it to a `BaseShellItem` but not have it shown in the Shell's menus and get the page to have have the hamburger nav menu by adding it as to a `FlyoutItem` in the `AppShell.xaml` and using `FlyoutItemIsVisible="False"`:

```xml
<FlyoutItem
        Title="Stat Page"
        FlyoutItemIsVisible="False"
        IsEnabled="True">

    <ShellContent
            Title="Page1"
            ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate local:Page1}"
            Icon="tab_about.png"
            Route="about" />
</FlyoutItem>
```