# Xamarin Form: Dropdown menu in Hamburger

Tags: xamarin, drop-down-menu

does anyone knows if I can create a dropdown menu in Hamburger in Xamarin Form?

The dropdown menu should be like this. Please help me thank you.
[dropdown menu in Hamburger](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7NUmg.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `Expander` from [Xamarin.community-toolkit](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/xamarin/community-toolkit/views/expander) but be informed that currently:

> The Expander control is known to show unwanted behavior when used in a ListView or CollectionView. At this time we recommend not using a Expander in one of these controls.

Here is [the issue](https://github.com/xamarin/XamarinCommunityToolkit/issues/1283) you want to follow since you are probably going to use it inside a `ListView` or `CollectionView` datatemplate.

Additionnally [Dynamically create list of FlyoutItem in Shell?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/65911023/5228202)